# Explanation gap in one of the translations of Uttarakand of ramayana... Please read below

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita, bhrigu

In Hari Prasad shashtri's Ramayana translation of uttarakand, we read durvasa narrating the curse of bhrigu that eventually made Rama bare separation with his wife, there are no such Sanskrit verses for the same in relevant chapters, what is the context for his supposed interpolation? And can this possibly be corroborated with the any scripture for that matter, let alone ramayana? As what all I have encountered are other variations of this curse which don't at all mention that Vishnu will have to abandon his wife.

Sanskrit verse alluding to the eventual abandonment of both Sita and Laxmana:

> > कस्मिंश्चित् करणे त्वां च मैथिलीं च यशस्विनीम् ।
> > संत्यजिष्यति धर्मात्मा कालेन महता किल ॥ १२ ॥

A rather more elaborative rendition of the same in Hari Prasad shashtri's translation:

> > Hearing the words of King Dasaratha, the highly effulgent Durvasa began to speak thus:—
> >
> > “‘Learn, O King, what happened formerly during the conflict between the Devas and Asuras. The Daityas, whom the Suras threatened, took refuge with the consort of Bhrigu and she, having given them a haven, they dwelt there in safety. Seeing them thus succoured, the Chief of the Gods, enraged, with his sharp-edged discus severed the head of Bhrigu’s wife.
> >
> > “‘Beholding the murder of his consort, Bhrigu, in his wrath, instantly cursed Vishnu, the destroyer of enemy hosts, saying:—
> >
> > “Since in thine insensate fury, you have slain my spouse, who should never have died thus, you shalt take birth in the world of men, O Janardana, and there you shalt live separated from your consort for many years.”
> >
> > “‘Having pronounced this curse, Bhrigu was overcome with remorse and his merits being exhausted by the malediction he had uttered, he began to propitiate that God, paying homage to the One who delights in penance and protects his devotees. Thereafter that God spoke, saying, “For the good of the worlds, I will be subject to your curse.”